# Contact form not sending email?

Tags: javascript, html, contact-form

I have a basic contact form and for some reason it won't send , any ideas: http://redline-interiors.com/contact.html

contact.html

```
    <ul class="contactform">
                    <li><label>Name </label><input type="text" id="namefield" name="contact_name" class="form_field contactInput required" /></li>
                    <li><label>Subject </label><input type="text" id="subjectfield" name="contact_subject" class="form_field contactInput required" /></li>
                    <li><label>Email </label><input type="text" id="emailfield" name="contact_email" class="form_field contactInput required email" /></li>
                    <li><label>Message </label><textarea  id="messagefield" name="contact_message " class="contactInput required"></textarea></li>
                    <li><button id="sendMessage" class="btn"><i class="icon-mail-2"></i> Send Message</button></li>
                </ul>
```

MainHandler.php

```
    include_once (dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/CONFIG.php');

    //Initial response is NULL
    $response = null;

    //Initialize appropriate action and return as HTML response
    if (isset($_POST["action"])) {
    $action = $_POST["action"];

switch ($action) {
    case "Initialize": {
            $mainData = array();

            include_once (dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/php/classes/class__twitter.php');
            $twitter = new LordWEBTweet();
            $twitts = $twitter->GetTweets($twitter_name, 3);

            $mainData["Twitts"] = $twitts;
            $mainData["Start_Date"] = $start_date;

            $response = $mainData;
        }
        break;
    case "SignUp": {
            if (isset($_POST["email"]) && !empty($_POST["email"])) {
                $subscriberEmail = $_POST["email"];
                include_once (dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/php/classes/class__mail.php');

                $messageText = 'You have new subscriber for your site.<br /><br />This is the subscribed email address<br />====================================<br />' . $subscriberEmail;

                $mail = new LordWEBMail();
                $response = ($mail->SendEmail($messageText, $signUpNotificationSubject, $signUpEmail, $email)) ? "Message Sent" : "Sending Message Failed";
            } else {
                $response = "Sending Message Failed";
            }
        }
        break;
    case "SendMessage": {
            if (isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["subject"]) && isset($_POST["message"])
                    && !empty($_POST["name"]) && !empty($_POST["email"]) && !empty($_POST["subject"]) && !empty($_POST["message"])) {
                include("classes/class__mail.php");
                $mail = new LordWEBMail();
                $response = ($mail->SendEmail($_POST["message"], $_POST["subject"], $_POST["email"], $email)) ? "Message Sent" : "Sending Message Failed";
            } else {
                $response = "Sending Message Failed";
            }
        }
        break;
    default: {
            $response = "Invalid action is set! Action is: " . $action;
        }
        }
    }

    if (isset($response) && !empty($response) && !is_null($response)) {
    echo '{"ResponseData":' . json_encode($response) . '}';
    }
    ?>
```

main.js

```
      $('#sendMessage').click(function(){    
        if(validateInput()){
            sendMail();
        }else
        {
            alert('Please fill all fields to send us message.');
        }
    });

        var validateInput = function(){
    var isValid = true;
    $('input, textarea').each(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('required'))
        {
            if($(this).val()!=''){
                if($(this).hasClass('email'))
                {
                    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
                    if(!emailReg.test($(this).val())){
                        isValid = false;
                        alert('Your email is not in valid format');
                    }
                }
            }else
            {
                isValid = false;
            }
        }
    });
    return isValid;
};

        var resetInput = function(){
    $('input, textarea').each(function() {
        $(this).val('').text('');
    });
};

var sendMail = function(){
    var params = {
        'action'    : 'SendMessage',
        'name'      : $('[name=contact_name]').val(),
        'email'     : $('[name=contact_email]').val(),
        'subject'   : $('[name=contact_subject]').val(),
        'message'   : $('[name=contact_message]').val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/mainHandler.php",
        data: params,
        success: function(response){
            if(response){
                var responseObj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                if(responseObj.ResponseData)
                    $('label.sendingStatus').text(responseObj.ResponseData);
                    showMessage('Your message was sent. Thank you!');

            }
            resetInput();
            $('#sendMail').removeAttr('disabled');
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            //xhr.status : 404, 303, 501...
            var error = null;
            switch(xhr.status)
            {
                case "301":
                    error = "Redirection Error!";
                    break;
                case "307":
                    error = "Error, temporary server redirection!";
                    break;
                case "400":
                    error = "Bad request!";
                    break;
                case "404":
                    error = "Page not found!";
                    break;
                case "500":
                    error = "Server is currently unavailable!";
                    break;
                default:
                    error ="Unespected error, please try again later.";
            }
            if(error){
                $('label.sendingStatus').text(error);
            }
        }
    });
        };
```

Edit : formatting the code to be able to understand easily. thanks anyone who answers. Removing the link since it is not allowed and no help since dead end.

Comment: You get an error in the console: POST http://redline-interiors.com/php/mainHandler.php 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 2):

You are posting your form data to http://redline-interiors.com/php/mainHandler.php

and this url doesn't exist

check for line 46 in your http://redline-interiors.com/js/main.js, if is the correct path or this file is missing in your server

```
url: "php/mainHandler.php"
```

Comment: In the console I don't get a 404 error now as it was missing so I added that to line 46 all the validation works but the email doesn't get sent. I've edited the question with some more code.

Comment: What do you get accessing http://redline-interiors.com/php/mainHandler.php in your browser? Here is Error 404: Not Found.

Comment: Just realised it's in the js folder http://redline-interiors.com/js/php/mainHandler.php I've fixed the errors that it gave but it still won't send an email.

Comment: so change in main.js line 46 for "js/php/mainHandler.php"

Comment: Changed this now I receive the js message "your email has been sent" and it clears the fields. But the email doesn't actually get delivered.